# Two seemingly equivalent paths in Linux, one works and one doesn't

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm in directory `~/www` and I'm trying to edit `~/.bashrc`.

I did `vi ../.bashrc` and Vim creates a new empty file.

I did `cd ..` and `vi .bashrc` and the correct file is opened.

Is this supposed to happen in Linux?

Edit:
I just tried `touch ../.bashrc` in `~/www` and I can't find the file that should've been created.

Comment: `vi ./bashrc` would edit `bashrc`, not `.bashrc`. Files starting with a `.` on *nix are hidden, use `ls -a` or `ls -la` to show them.

Comment: Typo, should be `vi .bashrc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will happen if the current directory is a symlink.

When you `cd` to a symlink, `..` will refer to the symlink target's parent:

```
$ ln -s /tmp mylink
$ cd mylink
$ pwd
/home/me/mylink
$ realpath .
/tmp
$ realpath ..
/
```

**However**, bash will confuse you by being clever and have `cd ..` behave differently. Here's `help cd`:

> `..' is processed by removing the immediately previous pathname component
>   back to a slash or the beginning of DIR.

This means that when you `cd ..`, bash will magically take you from `/home/me/mylink` to `/home/me`. This difference is very confusing, but also very useful.

If you use `cd -P ..`, this magic is not invoked, and it will take you from `/home/me/mylink` to `/`, just like all other tools would.

---

This is easier when you realize that `..` is not in any way special syntax that means "parent directory". Every directory actually has an honest-to-Linus entry named `..`

On older Unix systems, this was just a convenient convention, and `mkdir /foo/bar` would also automatically `ln /foo /foo/bar/..` which you could delete or relink as you wanted. Today, it is instead strictly enforced by the file system.

Obviously, `/tmp/..` links to `/`, and that doesn't change just because you followed a symlink to get to `/tmp`.